# Dodging to do conjugate gradient on the normal equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, soft-question, numerical-linear-algebra

Let us consider the linear equation system
$$\bf Ax = b$$

We can formulate it's normal equations:

$${\bf A}^T{\bf Ax=A}^T{\bf b}$$

but these are often harder to solve, because ${\bf A}^T{\bf A}$ has worse condition number than $\bf A$. Some time ago I stumbled upon this approach to formulate a linear equation system without normal equations:

$$\begin{bmatrix}\bf I&\bf A\\{\bf A}^T&\bf 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\bf r\\\bf x\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\bf b\\\bf 0\end{bmatrix}$$

Here we can see the constructed matrix is symmetric so we can avoid the normal equations, but at the expense of blowing up the space to dim(r)+dim(x).

How can we prove / realize that this choice will be better/faster?

Comment: I can't speak on this with much detail, but according to Demmel, a benefit to reformulating the problem in this way is that one can apply iterative refinement to the above system to obtain a more accurate solution (see page 134 of "Applied Numerical Linear Algebra").

Comment: Without being very familiar with this precise question, it is not impossible that casting normal equations into this block matrix presentation brings a **theoretical benefit**, for example by showing that it enters in this way in such and such category of problems... I have seen this in different cases.

Comment: For what it's worth, the normal equations aren't as hard to solve as they look, because Cholesky decomposition reduces the complexity of inverting a matrix of the form $A^TA$. So if we try proving the second approach is better, we should compare it to the cheapest way to solve the normal equations.

Comment: @J.G. : I did not write in question, but I am looking for the fastest way given that C-G or similar Krylov subspace related method is used.

Comment: I would like to add that this sort of matrices appear rather naturaly. For example in the framework of adjacency matrices of bipartite graphs : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3220378

Comment: What about using Krylov methods meant for non-symmetric matrices (eg BiCGstab)?

Comment: @tch Good idea. I shall take a look at it.

Comment: @tch : The matrix $A$ is usually not square in situations where you consider least square error solutions. Are there Krylov methods for non-square matrices?

Comment: Did you consider the usual QR approach? $A=QR$, then solve $Rx=Q^Tb$ in the upper, square, part.

Comment: @LutzL I am aware of the QR approach, that it can be both fast and popular, but sadly factorization is outside of the scope of my work right now. I am limited to iterative Krylov subspace methods with vector-vector and matrix-vector operations only.

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem to work in general.

The $\bf A$ matrix can for example be such that ${\bf B} = \begin{bmatrix}\bf I&\bf A\\{\bf A}^T&\bf 0\end{bmatrix}$ has non-positive eigenvalues. In this case Conjugate Gradient does not converge as it demands positive definiteness. We can circumvent by ${\bf B}^2{\bf x = Bb}$ but then the equation will meet same troubles as we tried avoiding with dodging normal equations in the first place.

However, if we instead run ***Biconjugate Gradient*** in Matlab, it seems to converge nicely.

I haven't read about the differences about this biorthogonalization thing or why it could work better.

Comment: Can someone please explain why this is not a good answer? Or any other reason for downvote?

Comment: I did not downvote, but where is it said that $A$ is square, and in general for square matrices $A^2$ will neither be symmetric nor have exclusively positive eigenvalues.

Comment: @LutzL yep you are right, I did a mistake there, I meant if we took the whole big matrix $^2$ (because we can fit $\bf I$ and $\bf 0$ so that it becomes square). I now gave it name $\bf B$ and changed to ${\bf B}^2{\bf x=Bb}$. Hmm Bb...