# Spectrum of adjacency matrix of bipartite graph is symmetric about the $y$-axis

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

I came across with the following theorem and it's solution in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3220357/spectra-of-adjacency-matrices-of-bipartite-graphs?noredirect=1):

> Theorem: It can be shown that for each eigenvalue $\lambda_i$, its opposite $−\lambda_i=\lambda_{n+1−i}$ is also an eigenvalue of $A$ if $G$ is a bipartite graph.
>
> Proof: Let $D$ be the diagonal matrix with $D_{i,i}=1$ if $i$ is in the first colour class and $D_{i,i}=-1$ if it is in the second. Then $DAD=-A$, so $A$ and $-A$ are similar and the spectrum of $A$ must be symmetric about the $y$-axis.

I'm trying to evaluate the proof a bit. What I did:

> Let $G=(V=L\cup R,E)$ be bipartite graph so $L\triangleq\left\{ 1,\ldots,\frac{n}{2}\right\} $ and $R\triangleq\left\{ \frac{n}{2}+1,\ldots,n\right\}$. Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of $G$. Lets mark $D$ to be $D_{i,i}=1$ if $i\in L$ and $D_{i,i}=-1$ if $i\in R$.

Now to finish the proof I have the following questions:

1. Why $DAD=-A$? Also, should not it be $D^{-1} AD=-A$?
2. Why spectrum of $A$ must be symmetric about the $y$-axis if $A$ and $-A$ are similar?

Comment: Note that $D^2=D\Rightarrow D=D^{-1}$ and
the parts of a bipartite graph do not necessarily have the same number of vertices. Your second question is answered in detail in the post you referred to.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the second question (even more details).

Similar matrices have the same eigenvalues and if $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of matrix $A$, then $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue of matrix $-A$. But then
$0=\operatorname{det}(-A-\lambda I)=(-1)^n\operatorname{det}(A+\lambda I)$. So $-\lambda$ is also an eigenvalue of $A$.

Thus, the eigenvalues of the matrix $A$ occur in pairs $\lambda_i,-\lambda_i$. It is possible that this is understood to be "symmetric about the $y$-axis".